# JS - getting a list of files and directories from a given directory

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to get a list of all files and directories in a specific path. lets say in "C:\Dir1"

Comment: Theirs is no way to do this from within a web page. Unless you are using IE, and are willing to remove all security restrictions.

Comment: Do you need to get the list of files from the server or from the client PC? For client side: **no you can't.**

Comment: Max - actualy I'm implementing a server and when i invoke my server, i'm given a root - that will be my resources for all clients. these files are actually on my computer..

Comment: @user1087995 So there is a server with files. One of the files it provides is a HTML with Javascript inside. Some client (read: user) opens that HTML and should see the list of files that are stored on the server. Am I right?

Comment: @user1087995 Then you should write all the details in your question. Currently it asks the wrong thing. Please modify your question and explicitly specify that you want to show **files on the server**, otherwise you'll receive wrong answers.

Comment: Ok. sorry.. I changed the question.

Comment: got it. i used : fs.readdirSync(folderspec)

Comment: Well, it would have been really nice of you to mention that you are talking about node.js

Answer (score 0):

you can use activex object as follow

```
 function   ShowFolderFileList(folderspec)   
{   
    var   fso,   f,   f1,   fc,   s;   
    fso   =   new   ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");   
    f   =   fso.GetFolder(folderspec);   
    fc   =   new   Enumerator(f.files);   
    s   =   "";   
    for   (;   !fc.atEnd();   fc.moveNext())   
    {   
          s   +=   fc.item();   
          s   +=   "&lt;br>";   
    }   
    return(s);   
}
```

refer http://forums.asp.net/t/1293557.aspx

Comment: Should be mentioned it only works in IE and only with security restrictions disabled.

Comment: folderspec is my root folder path? (i.e. "C:\dir1\")?

Comment: @Max Thanks i was forgotten to specify.

Comment: @ user1087995 yes folder path will be "C:\dir1\

Comment: @user1087995 Read my first comment to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use [findit](https://github.com/substack/node-findit)

```
var finder = require('findit').find(__dirname);
var files = [];

finder.on('path', function (file, stat) {
    files.push(file);
});

finder.on('end', function () {
    console.log(files);
});
```